# regex issue evaluating special characters

Tags: regex

I have a field being used to either search for an existing asset or create a new one

the search uses just the asset id
e.g
1234

and the create includes some extra fields comma separated
e.g

```
1234,5678,9101112,131415
```

so the regex i'm using is below (and it looks to be working correctly

```
((\w+)(,\w+){3})|^\w+
```

My problem is occasionally the asset id can be hyphenated 
e.g
clone1-12

I've tried updating my regex to

```
((\w+\-?\w*)(,\w+){3})|^\w+
```

but it doesn't seem to process the hyphen. is there something else i should be doing?

---

To help clarify

it follows a format
AssetID, Serial No, Part No, Model No

So that one text box validates that the entry is either just the assetID or that it is AssetID, Serial No, Part No, Model No

The other fields are pretty static in layout (always alphanumeric and no special characters), it's just the assetid that can include a hyphen

Comment: Have you tried to backslash the hyphen?

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: well it doesn't match,
so
alpha <- match
alpha-alpha <- no match
alpha,alpha,alpha,alpha  <- match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second branch of your regex is still `^\w+`. You should probably change that to `^[\w-]+`.

Comment: I misread that comment originally. thanks Roland
i ended up with 
((\w+\-?\w*)(,\w+){3})|^(\w+\-?\w*)$

Answer (score 0):

The correct regexp would be: `([\d\-]+)+`
It will get all digits + hyphens as separate groups regardless of how many of the m there are.

Also, you can use [this resource](https://regex101.com/) to check your regexps online and get a detailed explanation on each symbol.

**EDIT**: In case you wonder, here is the explanation on my version of regexp:

```
1st Capturing Group ([\d\-]+)+
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    *A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data*
        Match a single character present in the list below [\d\-]+
        + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
            \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
            \- matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: sorry i should have specified, the id can be alphanumeric hyphen whatever e.g. clone1-1. But when creating a new asset the barcode has to match the format alphanumeric,alphanumeric,alphanumeric,alphanumeric.

Comment: @Damage, than it should be something like this, I suppose: `([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)+|^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+` with `A-Z` part being optional (depends on whether you allow an upper-case characters as well)

Comment: weird ('m using this tool https://regex101.com/)
following your advice i tried switching to this
(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)+(,\w+){3})|^\w+

It'll match this
clone11-123,123,123,123

but not 
clone11-123

Comment: @Damage, because clone11-123 is not matched with first alternative `(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)+(,\w+){3})` and than it is tried by the second part - `^\w+` which says *any number of any alphanumeric characters, but no other symbols*. Try `(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)+(,\w+){3})|^[\w\-]+`